# i want to parse a string between two -'s by using regexp

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

i want to parse the values between -. but for some data like 1st url contains -- so in that case i need to get the gap only and the next one i am able to get `**camry**` successfully by using `*(site_data,'[^-]+',1,2)*`. but i want to handle the gap as well.

```
U=Google--undefined|http://www.google.com/urlsa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFMQFjAB&url=http://www.toyota.com/tundra/features.html&ei=-zwQUvOyGIXu2QWC7oGgBg&usg=AFQjCNFQKGcr2dbDeC-0zagtYdKFEfXXzQ&bvm=bv.50768961,d.aWc

U=Bing-camry-undefined|http://www.bing.com/searchq=camry&pc=MOZI&form=MOZSBR
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the string along with the hyphens, and then trim the hyphens.

```
trim('-' from regexp_substr(site_data,'-[^-]*-'))
```

Alternatively, you can also use regexp_replace function.

```
regexp_replace(site_data,'(-([^-]*)-)|(.)','\2')
```

Comment: that's why my worry. even i am getting -, but i d't won't to get -. where ever data like 1st example it's needs to throw Null

Comment: @Dileep, check the sample fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/16456). It is giving null in the first case.